# Need to keep <br> in text block tags while using import.io

Tags: import.io

Looking to do something relatively straightforward, I'm scraping text which so far I have had no problem grabbing, but I need to keep the `<br>` tags because white space analysis is an important part of the dataset.

Is there a way to keep the `<br>` tags so I can turn them into `\n\r`later on.

Example:

```
<p>
<span>Some text.</br></span>
<a>Some more text.<br></a>
<span>Some more more text.<br></span>
</p>
```

I need : `Some text.<br>Some more text.<br>Some more more text.<br>`

Right now I get: `Some text. Some more text. Some more more text.`

Advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to get the html format of your selection , all you have to do is change the column type from Text to HTML , also there is no way to get only the text + the `<br>`.

Comment: Got it- missed the html option - suppose I'll just regexp after. Thanks!

Comment: yeah if your data is always between the tags you can filter with regex after you select , no problem